# Prove that $DT = I_v$, $TD \neq I_v$, where $D$ = differentiation operator and $T$ is integration

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, derivatives, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the linear space of all real polys $p(x)$. Let $D$ denote the differentiation operator, and let $T$ the integration operator that maps each polynomial $p$ onto the polynomial $q$ given by $q(x) = \int_0^x p(t) dt$. Prove that $DT = I_v$ and $TD \neq I_v$. Describe the null space and range of $TD$.

$My$ $Previous$ $work$:

$D\int_0^x p(t) dt = D(P(x) -P(0)) = D(P(x)) - D(P(0)) = p(x)$. First, is this correct? It can't be because $p(x)$ can't be $I_v$ (which I take to mean the identity element in $V$).

$\int_0^x Dp(t) dt  = \int_0^x p'(t) dt = p(x) - p(0)$. I'm not sure what to do with this? And what is the null space and range of this?

Comment: You showed that $TDp = p$ iff $p(0)=0,$ which is not true for all polynomials, thus it cannot be the identity __operator__ $I_V: p \mapsto p$ in $V$ which maps every $p$ to itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $DT$ and $TD$ can't be both equal to identity. Otherwise it would mean that $D$ and $T$ are invertible, and are inverses of each other. At the same time, $D$ has non-zero kernel. Namely, constant polynomials. So $D$ can't be invertible. Contradiction. So $DT$ and $TD$ can't be both equal to identity.

Your proof that $DT=I$ is correct, because what you have shown is $DT(p(x))=p(x)$ for any $p(x)$.

Therefore $TD\neq I$. Since $T$ has zero kernel, $\ker(TD)=\ker(D)=\{\text{const polynomials}\}$.

Since $D$ is surjective, the range of $TD$ is the same as range of $T$, which is spanned by polynomials with zero constant term (easy to check).

Comment: Thanks. But why isn't D invertible? I have a hard time following your reasoning in the first paragraph.

Comment: Because it has non-zero kernel. You have, for example, $D(1)=0$. Suppose $D$ is invertible, i.e. $\exists D^{-1}$. Then $0=D^{-1}(0)=D^{-1}D(1)=I(1)=1$. Contradiction.

Comment: So what about then null space and range of TD?

Comment: One more question. How do we know that D is surjective? And why does this entail that range of TD is the same as range of T?